# Action bar not showing text and icons on pre Lollipop devices

Tags: java, android, xml

So my app is almost done. I have Xperia Z1 which runs Android Lollipop and everything looks fine on it.

Today I sent APK file to my friend who have Xperia T which runs on Android 4.3

He said that everything runs perfect, except actionbar is not showing text or icons. It shows text and icons only on activities that have ListViews.

I don't even know what code to past here.. So if anyone could help I would be thankfull. And please write down what code do you want me to copy.

This is how activites look like:

```
public class BlaBlaBla extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_programi_specijalizacija_ruke);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and styles

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>


    <style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item><!-- text size in menu-->
        <item name="android:background">#f2f2f2</item>
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">36dp</item><!-- item size in menu-->
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme.BrandedLaunch" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/branded_logo</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        />
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

styles v21

```
<resources>>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>

        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/black</item>


    </style>
</resources>
```

styles v19

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>


    <style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item><!-- text size in menu-->
        <item name="android:background">#f2f2f2</item>
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">36dp</item><!-- item size in menu-->
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme.BrandedLaunch" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/branded_logo</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        />
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

And in AndroidManifest all activities have this:

```
 android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```

Comment: You could try including the menu XML file where you declare your menu items. And if you are using `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: In all java files class name  extends AppCompatActivity. Could this be related to styles.xml?